# Remove Shapefile lock

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I have an ArcObject Dissolve procedure that creates a shp in a directory.  This dissolved layer is a temp layer and is not added into ArcMap.  I would like to delete it when the user clicks a button again, however it will not delete because their is a lock file (Dissolved.shp.6H8Z5D1.3448.1520.sr.lock) in the directory that happens after the dissolve gp runs:

```
pSumTable = pGeoProc.Dissolve(pInputTable, True, "ROUTE", "Dissolve.Shape, Minimum.ROUTE", pdatasetname2)
```

I looked at [Using Scheme Locks](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004qw000000), however I'm not using this layer to perform any edits.  [I also found this post on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/how-do-i-remove-schema-locks-from-a-file-geodatabase-in-java-in-arcgis-9-3), however it too does not seem to apply for my situation.  How do I remove this sr lock file (my entire code below), while keeping the ArcMap session open?

Thanks

```
 Try

            'delete all temp files
            Dim s As String
            For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("J:\20111030\GIS\Scripts\TempData2")
                System.IO.File.Delete(s)
            Next s

            'dissolve route layer
            Dim pMap As IMap

            pMap = mxdoc.FocusMap

            Dim pInputFeatLayer As IFeatureLayer

            pInputFeatLayer = featurelayer

            If pInputFeatLayer Is Nothing Then

                MessageBox.Show("The testinline layer was not found")
                Exit Sub

            End If

            Dim pInputTable As ITable
            pInputTable = pInputFeatLayer

            If pInputTable Is Nothing Then

                MsgBox("Table QI failed")
                Exit Sub

            End If

            If pInputTable.FindField("ROUTE") = -1 Then

                MsgBox("There must be a field named MUSYM layer ")
                Exit Sub

            End If

            Dim pInputFeatClass As IFeatureClass
            pInputFeatClass = featurelayer.FeatureClass

            Dim pfeatureclassname As IFeatureClassName
            pfeatureclassname = New FeatureClassName

            With pfeatureclassname

                .FeatureType = esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple
                .ShapeFieldName = "Shape"
                .ShapeType = pInputFeatClass.ShapeType

            End With

            Dim pNewWSName As IWorkspaceName
            pNewWSName = New WorkspaceName

            pNewWSName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriCore.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory.1"
            pNewWSName.PathName = "J:\20111030\GIS\Scripts\TempData2\"

            Dim pdatasetname2 As IDatasetName

            pdatasetname2 = pfeatureclassname
            pdatasetname2.Name = "Dissolved"

            pdatasetname2.WorkspaceName = pNewWSName

            Dim pGeoProc As IBasicGeoprocessor
            Dim pSumTable As ITable
            pGeoProc = New BasicGeoprocessor
            pSumTable = pGeoProc.Dissolve(pInputTable, True, "ROUTE", "Dissolve.Shape, Minimum.ROUTE", pdatasetname2)
            Dim pOutputFeatClass As IFeatureClass
            pOutputFeatClass = pSumTable

            If pOutputFeatClass Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox("FeaturesClass QI Failed")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim pOutputFeatLayer As IFeatureLayer
            pOutputFeatLayer = New FeatureLayer
            pOutputFeatLayer.FeatureClass = pOutputFeatClass
            pOutputFeatLayer.Name = pOutputFeatClass.AliasName

            ' CLEAN UP
            featurelayer = Nothing
            pInputFeatLayer = Nothing
            pInputTable = Nothing
            pInputFeatClass = Nothing
            pfeatureclassname = Nothing
            pNewWSName = Nothing
            pdatasetname2 = Nothing
            pGeoProc = Nothing
            pSumTable = Nothing
            pOutputFeatClass = Nothing
            pOutputFeatLayer = Nothing

            pMap = Nothing
            mxdoc = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: I have had issues deleting files that are inside a workspace I still am maintaining a reference to. I typically run a garbage collection after nullifying any remaining references to the workspace and it will delete properly. Oddly enough, it sometimes maintains a schema lock, but if I run a tight loop with repeated delete attempts after a short timer, it will work.

Comment: @Nathanus, Thanks for your reply. Do you have any code examples you could post using your method? I'm guessing I have to remove reference either to pSumTable or pdatasetname2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::ReleaseComObject to destroy the ArcObjects before you disassociate their reference.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comment, @artwork21 (which stems from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/schema-lock-issue-when-using-itable-addfield-via-arcobjects)), the code I used looks like this. I apologize for it being in C#, but I am not familiar enough with vb.net to provide a proper conversion.

```
private void deleteOldData(IFeatureWorkspace fWorkspacee)
    {
        IDataset olddataset = CheckForTempData(fWorkspace as IWorkspace);
        int i = 0;
        while (olddataset != null)
        {
            fWorkspace = null; //This should remove the lock that prevents deletion
            GC.Collect();
            try
            {
                olddataset.Delete();
                olddataset = null;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(100); 
                //There seems to be a delay in lock removal, so this is added as a stopgap
                if (i >= 10)
                {
                    setnttext("Error encountered deleting old temp data. Breaking Process.\n" + err.Message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

The `ReleaseComObject` method is something used to remove all references to a COM object so it can be released from memory, which should remove all locks. I have had spotty luck with it of late, for whatever reason, but here is some code (again, in C#) that has worked in the past.

```
IWorkspace workspace = CreateFileGdbWorkspace(gdbpath, gdbtext);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workspace);
```

I do not believe you can use `FinalReleaseComObject` or `ReleaseComObject` after you set a reference to `null` however. I think I remember that causing an error about non-existent COM objects in my program. In your case, you would simply use `ReleaseComObject` on all of the variables you set to `nothing` before you remove the reference. Note that `FinalReleaseComObject` performs the looping that you see in the help document you linked in @Jim B's answer. It does the release over and over until the reference count becomes 0.

Answer (score -4):

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(featClass);

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please consider adding context to this to make a complete answer.  You can take our tour to get up to speed on the site here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour